# premature end of file

Tags: android, xml

I haven't found any solution, some people ask almost the same thing, but that doesn't help me.

So, I would like to define a menu for an Android appication.

I have create a folder named `menu` in "res" and when I create an xml file, I have an error :
"Premature end of file"

This error is on the first line of my xml file which is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

And in the file I have only this other line :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu>
```

In the console I have this error :

```
" Error in an XML file: aborting build. "
```

If anyone had the same problem or understand my problem can you help me, I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: im not able to see the lines, did you paste them properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add at least one item in the menu; for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:title="Test/>

</menu>
```

Comment: I had try and it doesn't work but with what you write it's work i don't know why. Thanks

Comment: The only difference I see in the first line is that you have UTF in uppercase, but I don't have any resource to backup the theory that the encoding it's only accepting lowercase :) If the answer was useful, and you solved your problem, think about accepting is, so that others can know your question is closed.